# Woocommerce - Shortcode to show products which contains custom text on their name/title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

So, i know the "**products**" WooCommerce shortcode is very powerful and can show a list of products by tag, category, attribute etc, but can't find any option to show products containing a word/s on their name/title or even description, for example, let's say i have a list of products which names are: **red car, yellow motorbike, white truck, yellow submarine**.

So i need something like `[products limit="4" columns="4" in_name="yellow"]`

Which should list "**yellow motorbike**" and "**yellow submarine**" products (`in_name`).

I know i can do something similar with tags, but i have 3000+ products so i can't create hundreds of tags and then edit every single product to add the tag/s to them :(

**Thanks** for your help in advance guys, you're always very helpful =D

Comment: Nice question. I looked into WC code and couldn't find a quick solution for this using a filter somehow. But I could recommend to use a bulk edit plugin, which will help you easily adding tags, even to your 3000+ products store base. This way even searching will be faster and it will be helpful for you in the future